# Postgresql trigger

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE  TRIGGER TRG_GPS
   AFTER INSERT ON "GPS"
   FOR EACH ROW

   BEGIN

     IF :new.Lat THEN
       INSERT INTO gps ("lat", "long","speed","course","time","date","imei","engine") VALUES (:new.Lat,:new.Long,:new.Speed,:new.Course,:new.Time,:new.Date,:new.Engine);
     END IF;

   END;
```

как исправить ошибка

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BEGIN"
LINE 5:    BEGIN
           ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 70

Comment: *Где ошибка?* В логике. У тебя в триггере логика такая - после вставки (т.е. запись - уже вставлена) проверить `:new.Lat`, и если там не NULL/False - вставить ещё одну запись (походу с теми же значениями?)...

Comment: Ну и если ошибка - то, вероятно, есть и сообщение об ошибке. А коли так - не надо её прятать, надо, наоборот, процитировать...

Comment: вот ошибка ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BEGIN"
LINE 5:    BEGIN
           ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы написали либо какие-то мысли о триггере либо для какой-то другой СУБД, не `postgresql` отмеченного в теге.

В `postgresql` триггер создаётся определённым образом и этот способ вообще не похож на то что вы написали. Запрос в вопросе больше синтаксис `mysql` напоминает, или что-то в том духе.

Пример создания триггера в postgresql есть в документации, например [при использовании `pl/pgsql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html):

```
CREATE FUNCTION emp_stamp() RETURNS trigger AS $emp_stamp$
    BEGIN
        -- Check that empname and salary are given
        IF NEW.empname IS NULL THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'empname cannot be null';
        END IF;
        IF NEW.salary IS NULL THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION '% cannot have null salary', NEW.empname;
        END IF;

        -- Who works for us when they must pay for it?
        IF NEW.salary < 0 THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION '% cannot have a negative salary', NEW.empname;
        END IF;

        -- Remember who changed the payroll when
        NEW.last_date := current_timestamp;
        NEW.last_user := current_user;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$emp_stamp$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER emp_stamp BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON emp
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION emp_stamp();
```

Как легко заметить, какие-то общие слова с вашим запросом есть, но синтаксис сильно отличается. Поэтому полностью закономерно удивление базы на ваш запрос.